# Staying notified of when there are updates to vendor scripts

Tags: javascript, github

I own a web app that uses various vendor scripts (both javascript and CSS). Basically all of them have their repository on GitHub.

Every few months, I look to see which version of each vendor script I have deployed on my site, and have to manually go to the vendor's website to see if there's any update. If there is… I want to see the changelog so I can do an impact assessment.

I frequently notice I've missed major releases or security patches. This means I'm always a few weeks behind the 8 ball.

Is there a solid way to stay informed of if there are new stable releases without having to find an email list I can subscribe to for each individual vendor?

Comment: I don't think so. It's a nice idea so I'm going to look into developing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For github projects, you can subscribe to the release tag for project via RSS.

Some examples:

- https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/tags.atom
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tags.atom